# Kinect+Processing: detect where user arm+hand is pointing?

Tags: processing, kinect

I have an idea for a project but, as I've never used the kinect before I want to know if it can be done with it. What I want to do is to find out where a user is pointing to (in 3d space). Then ok, I want to detect the skeleton of his arm (and I saw this can be done) and then virtually 'extend' it (drawing a line for example) to check where is pointing in the space. Basically I will have a wall and I want to find out where (which area) the user arm is pointing on that wall (and the user won't be touching the wall, of course).
If you know any interesting source I'd really appreciate it.

sorry for my english.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Getting the arm's skeleton and projecting won't help you: there is no way of telling where the Kinect is relative to the screen, so you won't know to what point in the screen the user is pointing. You could achieve something like that using calibration: ask the user to point to the center of the screen, save that coordinate, and then do all the calculations relative to that one.

Comment: What if the kinect was fixed on a wall (let's say 3 meters from floor) and I want to detect where the user (standing in front of the wall and the kinect) is pointing on that wall?